# Excel Power Query identify hidden rows

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I have a source sheet and I have to extract data of it with power query.
Some of these rows in the source are hidden. I want to flag these hidden rows.

Source: (the hidden flag in "A" is not in the data, it is normal Excel Row hidden)

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| test1 | 78978 |
| test2 //hidden | 2323 |
| test3//hidden | 15 |
| test4 | 2323 |

Result should be

| A | B | hidden_flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| test1 | 78978 | 0 |
| test2 | 2323 | 1 |
| test3 | 15 | 1 |
| test4 | 2323 | 0 |

Is it anyhow possible?
I have tried to add a Index which represents the row numbers. But I don't know how to check in Power Query if the row is hidden or not.

Filtering on Column A in Power or changing/adding flag in the data source is unfortunately not an option.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Tabelle1"]}[Content],
    #"Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type)
in
    #"Index"
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this within Power Query, but you could add a column to your Data Table which can show 1 or 0 depending on whether the row is hidden or not.

eg.    `C2: =SUBTOTAL(103,[@A])`

Then when you import the table into PQ, the hidden rows will show zero, and the visible rows a one.

If you cannot modify your original source, suggest you write a VBA routine which duplicates the original table in a hidden workbook or worksheet, and then delete that after processing through Power query.

[image]